# How InfluxDB leverages the underlying key value store?

Tags: influxdb, key-value-store

I am doing some research on InfluxDB and found out that it uses an underlying Key-Value store for storage (like LevelDB, RocksDB, etc.).

I would like a mental model of what kind of keys are created for storing the time series data.

I am guessing something along the lines of "starting timestamp -> list of values...." but would like a more precise explanation about that.

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB works a little differently.

> An InfluxDB database stores points. A point has four components: a measurement, a tagset, a fieldset, and a timestamp.
>
> The measurement provides a way to associate related points that might have different tagsets or fieldsets. The tagset is a dictionary of key-value pairs to store metadata with a point. The fieldset is a set of typed scalar values—the data being recorded by the point.
>
> The serialization format for points is defined by the [line protocol] (which includes additional examples and explanations if you’d like to read more detail). An example point from the specification helps to explain the terminology:

`temperature,machine=unit42,type=assembly internal=32,external=100 1434055562000000035`

> The measurement is temperature.
>
> The tagset is machine=unit42,type=assembly. The keys, machine and type, in the tagset are called tag keys. The values, unit42 and assembly, in the tagset are called tag values.
>
> The fieldset is internal=32,external=100. The keys, internal and external, in the fieldset are called field keys. The values, 32 and 100, in the fieldset are called field values.

You can check out this post for the full explanation of the internals. https://www.influxdata.com/blog/influxdb-internals-101-part-one/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)